# PHP Logging option to log all function calls?

Tags: php, logging

Is there a PHP(or Apache?) option to enable logging of every function call  possible in my server side code?
(I would like to use this rather than error_log for logging/analyzing the code flow)

Comment: Have you looked into xdebug profiling?

Comment: Work OOP and put it in some kind of router model, that is the way i do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [**xDebug**](http://xdebug.org/) that the thing you are asking for.

Comment: More precisely, read http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace. To start/stop tracing at a specific location in your code enclose it bedtween <?php xdebug_start_trace('c:/tmp/trace.xt'); ?> and <?php xdebug_stop_trace(); ?> !

Comment: Website is down, could you explain the process more detailed, please?

Comment: [Updated link for function traces](https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not allowed to install [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org) you can try [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)